# Radio buttons are checked simultaneously

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I've been trying to replicate this page https://vk.com/ You can see that they've changed the standard appearance of radio buttons in the 2nd form.

I succeeded in changing the design of the buttons but now they are all checked simultaneously.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form2">
  <div class="heading">
    <h2>Poprvé na VK?</h2>
    <p>Okamžitá registrace</p>
  </div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Vaše jméno" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Vaše příjmení" required class="last-name">
  <label class="birth">
    <span>Datum narození
      <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o"
         aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <input type="date" class="date" required>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span class="gender-head">Pohlaví</span>
    <div class="gender">
      <input type="radio" id="1-option" name="selector" value="female" class="control">
      <div class="button"></div>Žena
      <input type="radio" id="2-option" name="selector" value="male" class="control">
      <div class="button"></div>Muž
      <input type="radio" id="3-option" value="other" name="selector" class="control">
      <div class="button"></div>Jiné
    </div>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Zaregistrovat se</button>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Přihlásit se přes Facebook</a>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form {
  width: 290px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #E0E1E3;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.form2 {
  margin-right: 10px;
  clear: right;
  height: 380px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  color: #333436;
  justify-content: center;
}

.form2 .heading {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form2 h2 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.form2 p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 2px 0 0 9px;
}

.form2 input {
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #DBDCDE;
  width: 270px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form2 .last-name {
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.form2 span {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: #7A7B7D;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.form2 .birth {
  margin: -15px 0 0 10px;
}

.form2 .date {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}

.form2 .gender-head {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.gender {
  display: flex;
  width: 260px;
  margin: 15px 0 0px -10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000;
}

.gender input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

.gender .button {
  border: 1px solid #A3A4A6;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-right: -40px;
}

.gender .button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #EAEBED;
}

.gender .button::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .button {
  border: 1px solid #5A7CA3;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .button::before {
  background: #5A7CA3;
  margin: 3px 2px 2px 3px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #7A7B7D;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

.form2 button {
  height: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Skidle/u3zj66sd/

I haven't learned JavaScript yet so I'd prefer CSS & HTML only solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you! I used absolute position because it was in some other person's solution on radio buttons design. I guess I leave it like this for now and maybe return to it at some point later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the radio buttons, by removing the `position`, you can see that only one is selected, and it is correct for each selection:

[image: preview]

The problem lies in the way the presentation works. The CSS code:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .button::before   // Is wrong.
input[type="radio"]:checked + .button::before   // Is right.
```

**Explanation**

The code given for the CSS, `~` selector is a sibling selector, which selects **all** the selectors.

While, what you need is the `+` selector, which is the immediate or adjacent sibling selector. This selects only one.

Change needs to be done here:

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked + .button::before {
  background: #5A7CA3;
  margin: 3px 2px 2px 3px;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0rqu3s2c/**

> **Note:** There's an issue when you try to click on the other inputs. So, you might need to check what's blocking it. Please do not use `absolute` positioning without the desired result.